# Can't start HTTPD

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, exim

I'm trying to start httpd, but it only gives me '[FAILED]'. Now, I installed exim, but that didn't worked, so I uninstalled it. But then the web server didn't worked any more! I tried to `/etc/init.d/httpd start`, but that gives '[FAILED]' without a reason. What can I do to get it started?

`httpd -e debug` gives:

```
    [Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module auth_basic_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module auth_digest_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_file_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_alias_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_anon_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_dbm_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_default_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_host_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_user_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_owner_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_groupfile_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_dbm_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_default_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module ldap_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authnz_ldap_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module include_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module log_config_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module logio_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module env_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module ext_filter_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module mime_magic_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module expires_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module deflate_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module headers_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module usertrack_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module setenvif_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module mime_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module dav_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module status_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module autoindex_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module info_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module dav_fs_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module vhost_alias_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module negotiation_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module dir_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module actions_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module speling_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module userdir_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module alias_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module rewrite_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_balancer_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_ftp_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_http_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_connect_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module cache_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module suexec_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module disk_cache_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module file_cache_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module mem_cache_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module cgi_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module version_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module ssl_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module fcgid_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module perl_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module php5_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_ajp_module
[Wed Nov 23 11:47:25 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module python_module
```

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240915/apache-doesnt-start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try this first:

```
killall -9 httpd; /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

If that fails, I'd tail the error log and restart httpd:

```
tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/error_log &; /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Also, make sure nothing is already listening on port :80 with:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep :80
```

If some other procs has the port you can kill that pid. If you see

```
No space left on device
```

In the log file and you have disk space then you may need to clear up semaphores and restarte httpd with:

```
ipcs -s | grep nobody | gawk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -n 1 ipcrm sem && /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Another thing, it could be would be there are logs larger than 2GB. You'll usually see an error in your logs indicating this.

Comment: Great, it's running like a charm :D! Some stupid error in the error log did the trick..